# Confusion when making custom icon for ios

Tags: ios, user-interface, icons

I'm android developer and decide to make same version app for IOS, which this make me confuse when making an icon for IOS. In android developer docs they do mention

> creating 24 × 24 area in 32 × 32 (mdpi)

which mean the rest area (8x8) of the pixel will be white space. I will be using icon for a lot uses not only for toolbar, navigation, tabbar.

Here is my question

1. If I just use my own custom size say like 90x90 for every icon display include toolbar,navigation etc will it be reject on the review stage?
2. Assume I create an icon for navigation bar, 22x22 is the full icon size or mayb like 17x17 is the image size but the rest 5x5 should be white space.
3. What image should be include in image-asset, I have some crop image (400x150) which it use for display in advertise slider, should I include that to image-asset too? I do understand the benefit of using image-asset 2@x, 3@x but just too much confusion.

I been testing the app with all the icon I create in android,it about 100++ of icon, the final stage is to seetle down all the icon issues, appearciate for any help. Sorry for bad grammar.

Comment: Plz go through these links: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html,   https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use SVG format.

Steps to use SVG icons in Xcode:

1. Generate PDFs With the @1x Asset. You can use Adobe Illustrator or any other vector editing tool. ...
2. Create an Image Set in Your XCAsset File. ...
3. Set the Scale Factors to Single Vector. ...
4. Drag and Drop Your PDF Into the All, Universal Section. ...
5. Refer to Your Image by Its Name, Like for any PNG File.

Comment: I upvote your answer. I might modify and open a bounty for this one.